# Adding Watch OS 2 target into Xcode Unity Project ("Unsupported Family")

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, watchkit, apple-watch

I'm trying to add a Watch OS 2 target into my Unity Generated Xcode project.

When I go to select my Watch/Phone device combo to build onto, I get present with this "Unsupported Family" message. Any ideas how to get around this message?
[image]